# Export GraphQL result to CSV without pagination

Tags: graphql, api-platform.com

We have multiple lists that contain filters and are requested with GraphQL.

We want to export the results to a CSV. At the moment we created a controller that loops over the paginator by requesting the GraphQL endpoint and concats the result to one array.

Is there a native way to do it internally by reusing all the filters on the entities? Something like (psuedo code: `$GraphQLRunner→fetchResult($graphqlQLquery, $filters)`)

Comment: Solution was to instantiate the GraphQL executor:




`$executionResult = $this->executor
                ->executeQuery($this->schemaBuilder->getSchema(), $query, null, null, $variables)
                ->setErrorsHandler($this->errorHandler)
                ->setErrorFormatter($this->normalizer->normalize(...));`